# Relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I have a laptop in which software is installed by which I check a particular notification. So I am saying I will check the notification from my system and that notification is sent to me by someone.

I am a bit confused that how to use the sentence correctly below.

> A. the notification number which you send I will check in my laptop tomorrow.
>   B. I will check the notification number which you send in my laptop

Does the word order make a difference to the meaning?

Comment: Bill the meaning of you sentence is different and my different because I have a laptop in which a software installed through which I check the notification. So I  am telling  I will check the notification from my system and the notification sent to me by someone.

Comment: My hunch is `I will check on my laptop the notification number that you have sent.` Or, more formally, `I will check on my laptop the notification number which you have sent.` I don't have time to check this right now but perhaps, if that's the meaning that Hussain means to get across, someone else can come support it with real evidence.

Comment: The first part of your question says that you check notifications, but your example sentences say that you check notification numbers.  Should I assume that the notifications are merely numbers? Or (as seems more likely) are the numbers merely pointers by means of which you access the actual notifications?

Answer (score 1):

**"I will verify the notification number when I get on my laptop tomorrow."**  (In place of "verify" you might use some other term, depending on what you mean by "check'.  And you might prefer to use "sign on to" instead of "get on".)

> The notification number which you send I will check in my laptop
>   tomorrow.

This is understandable but not particularly idiomatic.

> I will check the notification number which you send in my laptop.

This is confusing.  On first scan it sounds like he's sending you your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to address the sender directly:

*"Send the notification number to my laptop and I will check it tomorrow."*

If you want to make the sentence conditional, start it with *"If"*.
If you want to make it a request, start it with *"Please"*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in meaning. In sentence A it is clear that a notification number is being sent, and the receiver will verify it in his laptop. In sentence B it is possible to interpret "the notification number which you send in my laptop" as a message which is sent within the receiver's laptop. In both sentences the relative pronoun should be "that" and not "which," so as to indicate a restriction of the notification number.

A. the notification number which you send I will check in my laptop tomorrow.
B. I will check the notification number which you send in my laptop

Answer (score -1):

A) This sentences doesn't seem to be correct to me.

You can write : " The notification number which you send  will be checked in my laptop by me tomorrow. " But it doesn't sound good to me too.

B) This sounds good. But don't use comma before "which " here unless you count it [ which you send]  as nonessential.

Comment: Shall I say  that  I will check the notification number which you send in my laptop.